# Помогите с vagrant на windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

Для работы в RoR пытаюсь поднять ВМ на windows 7 с помощью vagrant и Virtual Box.

Vagrant скачал и поставил с [vagrantup.com](http://vagrantup.com), Virtual Box отсюда: [virtualbox.org](http://virtualbox.org). Саму ВМ отсюда: github.com/rails/rails-dev-box.git. Но при выполнении команды vagrant up [происходит следующее](https://monosnap.com/file/mbcCutEDp8okVYBpjK4hff9l8QlnCV) то есть ничего. В диспетчере задач vagrant появляется и всё. В чём может крыться проблема?

Comment: В том, что процесс идёт, но идёт медленно? Создание новой виртуальной машины не мгновенно происходит.

Comment: Я понимаю что не мгновенно. Но я думаю что за 12-14 часов хоть что-то должно было произойти? Или такой период времени тоже "мгновенно"?

Comment: Многовато, да. В крупных городах за минуты должен справляться. То, что он ничего не выводит, тоже странно. Вы пробовали сделать это же из cmd? То же самое?

Comment: Да. Пробовал. Результат такой-же.

Comment: Похоже, что у вас какие-то общие проблемы с Vagrant. Можете открыть VirtualBox и посмотреть, создал ли Vagrant хотя бы одну машину. Независимо от этого, вам явно стоит обратиться куда-то в [сообщество Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/community.html), сомневаюсь, что проблема у вас в системе, скорее в Vagrant, и это нужно чинить.

Comment: В том-то и дело что не создаёт. За наводку благодарю.

Comment: У меня просто был случай, когда я не дал процессу vagrant завершиться, и обнаружил в VirtualBox недоделанную виртуалку. Но у вас даже процесс создания не начался, причём совершенно вглухую. Это не нормально.

Comment: Мда... Ладно "будем искать"

Answer (score 2):

Этот [баг](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8783) связан с PowerShell.

Обновите PowerShell до 4 версии (входит в комплект [Windows Management Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx%3Fid%3D40855))