# Vagrant: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vagrant

Начинаю работать с `Vagrant`, работаю по Getting Started https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/index.html

> Before diving into your first project, please install the latest version of Vagrant. And because we will be using VirtualBox as our provider for the getting started guide, please install that as well.

Установил на `Windows 7 x64` версию `Vagrant` `2.0.0` с официального сайта.
`Virtualbox` у меня установлен версии `5.1.14r112924`.

Обновил `Powershell`, чтобы исправить ошибку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724250/235330.

Далее по инструкции в новой папке выполняю

1. `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64`: появляется `Vagrantfile`;
2. `vagrant up`.

в инструкции сказано, что

> After running the above two commands, you will have a fully running virtual machine in VirtualBox running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit.

но я получаю ошибку

```
E:\VM\v_demo>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64"]
Error: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

При этом в папке создаётся следующая структура

```
|   Vagrantfile
|
\---.vagrant
    \---machines
        \---default
            \---virtualbox
                    vagrant_cwd
```

Поиск по этой ошибке приводит к использованию `curl` и `git`, о которых тут ни слова.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась из-за прокси сервера, через который я работаю. Дополнительно к `http_proxy` потребовалось указать переменную окружения `https_proxy=http://192.168.x.xxx:3128`. Это решило проблему.